# tasking compiler disable optimisations

Tags: compilation, compiler-optimization

how can I disable optimisations with TASKING compiler ? I'm using eclipse IDE

I've read in the documentation that I could use `#pragma` but didnt understand how

```
If you specify a certain optimization, all code in the module is subject to that optimization. Within the C
source file you can overrule the C compiler options for optimizations with #pragma optimize flag
and #pragma endoptimize. Nesting is allowed:
#pragma optimize e /* Enable expression
... simplification */
... C source ...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the TASKING compiler is compatible with GCC with respect to optimization level flags, per [this](http://www.tasking.com/support/tricore/tc_user_guide_v3.0.pdf) user guide (which is indeed quite old).

For disabling optimizations altogether, select `None (-O0)` as optimization level in the C/C++ project settings. Note that `-O0` is the default optimization level of the `Debug` configuration.

Screenshot (Eclipse Oxygen):

[image: Eclipse set O0]

If you wish to disable optimizations for a specific part of your C/C++ code, such as a specific function, then the pragma comes handy. For doing so place `#pragma optimize 0` before the start of the code, and `#pragma endoptimize` after the end of it.

For example:

```
#pragma optimize 0
void myfunc()  
{
   // function body
}
#pragma endoptimize
```

Comment: the second proposition worked for me but for the first, there is no Tool setting panel in my eclipse

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi On the left pane in Eclipse main view, you should see the project tree - right clicking the project name will open a drop down menu, in which you should click `Properties` (it should be the last option). This link from Eclipse documentation may be helpful:
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_properties.htm